# Java Partial message handling from socket NIO ByteBuffer

Tags: java, sockets, buffer, arrays, bytebuffer

I have a buffer that stores multiple messages.  Say the buffer is 50 bytes (let me try to illustrate this with metacode)

```
-------------------- (50 byte empty buffer)
```

and my messages are of size 20.  On a given socket read, I may get 1 message

```
 |111111111|-----------  (50 byte buffer with 1 20 byte message
```

Or two messages

```
 |111111111|222222222|----
```

But if I get three messages, I end up with a partial third message

```
 |111111111|222222222|3333 (TRUNCATE)
```

On the next socketread, the rest of the third message comes through and the bytestream contains the second half of message 3:

```
>>> socket.read() 
33334444444455555555 ....
```

Furthermore, I know the position at which the third message starts, so I'd like to simply retain the contents of the third message in my buffer.  I thought doing compact would be the case:

```
>>> readbuffer.compact()
```

And then simply pass this same buffer back into socket.read()

```
>>> socket.read(readBuffer)
```

And ideally, this would fill my buffer as so

```
33333333|44444444|55555...
```

However, I don't think that compacting and simply passing the readbuffer back into sock.read() is the correct approach.

Is there a well-known solution for handling partial messages this way?  I can think of a lot of things to try, but this has to be a common problem.  I'd like to avoid the intermediary creation of buffers as much as possible, but can't think of a solution that doesn't invoke some sort of a residual buffer.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that `compact()` isn't the correct approach? It is.

Comment: I tried printing the bytearray after the next socket.read() call, and I don't think socket.read() begins writing at the position of the buffer.  IE, if my last position is P, does the call to socket.read() start at P or start at 0?

Comment: It starts at P, just as per the Javadoc. A read is the same as a put.

Comment: Thank you.  Derp, I see it now (Suppose that a byte sequence of length n is read, where 0 <= n <= r. This byte sequence will be transferred into the buffer so that the first byte in the sequence is at index p and the last byte is at index p + n - 1, where p is the buffer's position at the moment this method is invoked. Upon return the buffer's position will be equal to p + n; its limit will not have changed. )

Comment: Can you put some sample example. I tried reading from the socket and then applied compact api after my 1st packet complete which was 275 bytes and buffer size was 512, but unfortunately my position remain same. Created state machine to validate the packet before moving to next.                                                         
var bytesRead = mUart.read(bb.array(), bb.capacity())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken. Using `compact()` and then reusing the buffer for the next `read()` is exactly the correct approach.